# Entity Framework - "The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file..."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create Repository Pattern with Unit of Work, I'm using Entity Framework Database-First and this error happens when I try to simply get data from database:

[image]

More specifically when I call this method the exception is thrown in the following method:

```
public TEntity Get(int id)
{
    return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
}
```

When I started debugging I found something interesting

[image]

This happens even if I try to directly access a context class and get the information.
I tried changing connectionStrings in App.config, and other simple things but nothing worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you instantiate the context? What is the connection string you are passing to the constructor? Database first connection strings are not regular.

Comment: Check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: After testing some cases I don't think that error is because of Unit of Work pattern. There are 2 layers: Data and Service. In Data layer I have my context class and I define a method which gets a data and gives to the Service layer. In another words, I call this method from service and that error happens. I have no idea why.

Comment: Have you checked the connection string?

Comment: It's a default connection string that is generated by Entity Framework. I created a console application, generated classes and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok, but you have to add that connection string to your app.config. It will not be used from a library .config file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. Should I change the connection string?

Comment: You should check that when the context is instantiated, the connection string it gets is in the proper format. Regular connection strings usable for cedefirst will throw that exsct exception when supplied to an edmx based context.

Comment: Why would EF generate a connection string for CodeFirst when I used the DB-First approach?

Comment: https://www.google.hu/amp/s/blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/26/dont-use-code-first-by-mistake/amp/